# d3.js force layout namespace in a backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, d3.js, backbone-views, backbone-boilerplate, force-layout

I'm working on a medium-complex app using backbone.js to handle wordpress data, and i can't figure out how to get the force working in a backbone layout.

basically, i'm trying to instantiate a force layout within a backbone boilerplate layout, like this:

```
myLayout = Backbone.Layout.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var f = this; // i.e. the layout instance
        f.force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(myModels)
            .on("tick", f.tick)
            .gravity(0)
            .friction(0.9)
            .start();

        console.log(f.force);
    },
    tick: function() {
        // stuff to do when the force ticks
    }
});
```

The problem is that the force is being defined with all blank functions, like `gravity: function(x) { //lots of null things here }`. i'm pretty sure it's a namespacing issue, but nothing i try works - i've tried doing `$(window).force`, `var force`, `$this.force`...

in my example `tick` is the only namespaced function, but i've tried doing that with all the others too (gravity, friction, etc.) to no avail (even though they should just be chaining onto the force object).

anyone have any ideas? i can't really post a .jsfiddle because the app is too complicated, so sorry in advance about that. The current version is up [here](http://learning.samgalison.com/wp_bb/)

**edit**: here's how d3 can access the models successfully:

this works:

```
myLayout.nodes = myLayout.d3_wrapper.selectAll(".node")
    .data(myModels)
    .enter().append("g").attr("class", "node")
    .attr("x",10)
    .attr("y",10);

    myLayout.nodes.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.get("slug"); })
```

as does this:
`myLayout.nodes.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.attributes.slug });`

**edit**: in the interest of clarity, here's the non-nicknamed code:

```
setforce: function() { // this gets called from the layout's initialize fn
    console.log("setting force");
    var f = this; // the layout
    f.force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(Cartofolio.elders.models) // Cartofolio is the module, elders is a Backbone Collection
        .gravity(0)
        .friction(0.9)
        .start();

    console.log(f.force);
}
```

Comment: What does the `myModels` variable contain?

Comment: it's a set of `Backbone.Models` from a `Backbone.Collection`, each of which has a bunch of `.attributes` - they get pulled fine by other d3 methods, it's just the `.force.layout` that seems to be finnicky

Comment: Would you post an example of how another `d3` method accesses the attributes on the models?

Comment: done - edited the question with that at the bottom

Comment: ps. d3_wrapper is just an <svg> to hold the whole thing

Comment: Thanks. So, the examples you posted are either using `model.get()` or `model.attributes` to access the attributes. In the case of the force layout, you're just passing the whole collection to `d3`. `d3` is not going to know that it needs to use `model.get()` or `model.attributes` to get attributes on your models. A simple solution might be to pass `myModels.toJSON()` to the force layout, but then you won't get any `change` events on your models...

Comment: ohhh... hm. do the force functions like gravity, friction, and tick really depend on access to the model attributes?

Comment: The [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-nodes) makes it sound that way.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `toJSON()` on your collection before passing it to `d3`:

```
myLayout = Backbone.Layout.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var f = this; // i.e. the layout instance
        f.force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(myModels.toJSON())
            .on("tick", f.tick)
            .gravity(0)
            .friction(0.9)
            .start();

        console.log(f.force);
    },
    tick: function() {
        // stuff to do when the force ticks
    }
});
```

Comment: no dice. I was also maybe unclear - myModels was a nickname for a direct array of the models inside a collection - so i'm giving d3 that array, not the collection. so - my collection is `Module.thecollection` and its models are `Module.thecollection.models`, which is what i'm passing to force. it won't let me call `Module.thecollection.models.toJSON()`, only `Module.thecollection.toJSON`, which doesn't really help because it's still one too many steps abstracted...

Comment: i added the real code so hopefully it's less confusing. I _do_ need to be able to listen to changes, so calling .toJSON isn't super ideal (although i suppose i could just re-JSON it each time)

Comment: Hmm. Using the `get` and `set` functions is the best way I know to trigger `change` events. It might be worth it to dive into the [Source Code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js#L190) for the force layout and add `get` and `set` calls in the appropriate places.

Comment: might be true. that's gonna be painful... what makes me think it's a namespacing issue is that even if i make it super literal, like `projects: [{//json literal list of projects}], setforce: fn() {//force setup function}` it doesn't change a damn thing. >.<